# CORS specifics in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, api

I don't get the difference in the behaviour of angular regarding the following two versions of my code.

v1: works seamlessly

```
onSubmit() {
// selects all marked as checked students from from
const selectedStudents = this.studentsFormGroup.value.students
.map((checked: boolean, index: number) => checked ?
  this.listOfStudents[index].id : null)
.filter((value: number) => value !== null);

// create Student in remote_db
selectedStudents.forEach((id: number) => {
  this.studentService.createStudentById(id);
  console.warn('student created: ' + id);
});
```

v2: gets me an

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/api/v3/students'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

```
onSubmit() {
// selects all marked as checked students from from
const selectedStudents = this.studentsFormGroup.value.students
.map((checked: boolean, index: number) => checked ? [
  this.listOfStudents[index].id,
  this.listOfStudents[index].name,
  this.listOfStudents[index].surname] : null)
.filter((value: any) => value !== null);

// create Student in remote_db
selectedStudents.forEach((student: any) => {
  this.studentService.createStudentById(student.id);
  console.warn('student created: ' + student);
});
```

Can anyone explain what i'm not getting? I need the second version because further in in the future code I will need the additional info of the array. Any suggestions how that can be done.

- I added the proxy.conf.json as suggested
- I verified my api backend (slim 4) - works for other services just fine...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to verify that `this.studentService.createStudentById` has been called with the same values for both cases? A quick glance lead me to believe that for v2 a call with "undefined" is possible. And that indirectly you are calling the wrong URL that by accident gets denied by your browser because of a missing CORS header.

Comment: Thanks. That put me on track. I got an 'undefined' indeed. this.studentService.createStudentById(student[0]) works out just fine. If you care, post your comment as an answer and I check it :)

Comment: In the case where you get that CORS error, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: i get a 500. pls check the comment below the answer for mote details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While

```
checked ?
  this.listOfStudents[index].id : null
```

makes sure that the "id" is "truthy" or "null" (and therefore filtered out afterwards) v2 does no such check and therefore the possibility of "undefined" IDs can arise that cause the wrong URL being targetted.

Comment: my code in v2 produces a simple array that cannot be targeted with a named key. therefore as you stated in your comment, it got me an undefined and thus a server 500 feedback. i will take care of my api now for better error handling :) thanks for your time